# How to implement load on demand in ADO.Net?

Tags: .net, ado.net, lazy-loading

I want to show huge data in a grid view without paging, but by providing "load more" option to retrieve the next page and keep the previous one.

How to implement this feature using either EF or ADO.Net components?

I think that `.Skipe`, `.Take` methods in L2SQL or EF won't help because they will re-execute the query every *load* request. But what I want to implement is something similar to an open DataReader which saves the result regardless of what's happening in database (adding/deleting records). The only problem in DataReader is it shouldn't be kept open.

What's the standard way?

Answer (score 1):

**The standard way is to use Skip/Take and reexecute the query for each loaded segment.** This solution is easy and, more importantly, stateless. You certainly don't want to keep an open connection/command/query around for longer than the current HTTP request takes to execute. This is an anti-pattern because your app becomes stateful and fragile.

If the query is very expensive, consider storing the first 5 pages or so in a new table made for that purpose, so you can quickly retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Normal paging would also re-execute the query, so I don't think that should matter.

Your only two choices are either do some sort of paging (skip/take are a fine implementation of that, although actual paging may have perf benefits)

or

Save it all into a datatable or something. You don't get any perf benefits of paging that way, but you do give the user the ability to only load some records at a time, which may be a nice usability bonus.

Comment: What is "actual paging"? Skip and Take translate to SQL.